# My PS2 can't play music CD's

Tags: technical-issues, ps2

I had my PS2 for quite a while. I tried to play CD's i bought and it went fine, but the ones i made by dragging the files over the CD, the PS2 said i needed a PlayStation format disc. I don't know what's causing this because i putted my CD which was formatted in Windows 7 PC but when i got this CD in for the first time i got this:[image: Photo (Just a screenshot)]

I chose "Like a USB flash drive" and continued on with the files. I putted music, photos etc. And PS2 can't detect that.
[image: A photo of the error (Not captured by me. Googled it up)]

Also i see someone saying that screen is a creepypasta and scary thing but infact im not scared of that. It wasn't defective from anything, I did take care of this console my best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I chose "Like a USB flash drive"

There's your problem right there.  The PS2 can't read that format.  If you select "With a CD/DVD player" instead, it should work.

Comment: i think i cant go back

Comment: i might have to throw my cd away.

Comment: You would be correct there.  You'll have to use a new CD.

Answer (score 1):

PS2 can't read mp3 files. To be able to play the music with the PS2 music player, you have to burn the CD as an Audio CD, which means 60 minutes of music per regular 700mb CD.

Comment: And this can't be done by dragging and dropping files, you need a program like nero for that.. and yes, you can't use that CD for that anymore